# bash - how to read WIN PATH and set each single directory in to array

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, path

PATH value is some WIN PATH (remark- $PATH should be inserted to XML file)

example:

```
 PATH="EMRA\ER1\C&amp;W GU SEY\UR Dir"
```

OR

```
 PATH="TRQ\nb vf\EMRA\ER1\C&amp;W GU SEY\Last Dir" 

 etc ..... so on
```

my target is to create bash script that count how many directories exists in the $PATH

and set each directory in array

.

Let’s say that we want to print the directories names from the follwoing $PATH

```
PATH="EMRA\ER1\C&amp;W GU SEY\UR Dir"
```

then we will get the following results

```
for ((i=0;i<=$Num_of_dir_in_path;i+=1))
do 

[[ ! -z  ${DIR[$i]}  ]] && echo ${DIR[$i]}  

done



EMRA
ER1
C&amp;W GU SEY
UR Dir
```

the problem is I not understand how to count the directories in the $PATH
and how to set them in the array

( its more difficult when directory include space )

Comment: the key point here is: what is the delimiter between directories? Split on it and count the pieces

Comment: `IFS='\\' read -a array <<< "$Path"`

Comment: the delimiter is "\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the paths are separated by a backslash, which means that you can read them into an array like this:

```
$ IFS='\' read -ra paths <<<"EMRA\ER1\C&amp;W GU SEY\UR Dir"
$ for path in "${paths[@]}"; do
>    echo "$path"
> done
EMRA
ER1
C&amp;W GU SEY
UR Dir
```

I would be careful using uppercase variable names in the shell. `$PATH` in particular is a very important internal variable!

As [JID](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4453924/jid) points out, if you only wanted to print the paths out, rather than do anything else in the loop, you could just use `printf` instead:

```
printf '%s\n' "${paths[@]}"
```

Comment: Can use `printf '%s\n' "${paths[@]}"` instead of the loop